# How come Dory's voice changes when she grows, but not her parents?

Tags: finding-dory

In Finding Dory 2016, it shows us Dory as she was a little fish. Her voice is cuter and high-pitched. Then we see her parents. They have grown voices. Skip forward a little bit. Maybe a decade later, Dory is grown up and has her Iconic voice, but when she see's her parents they sound *exactly* like they did earlier in the movie. Should Filmmakers make their older characters sound older in the present, but younger in flashbacks?

Here is my question: **Why do filmmakers chose to age kids' voice but keep parents' voice sound like they haven't aged at all? Wouldn't that confuse the younger audience?**

Comment: This is just pedantry, I believe. It's a kids' movie.

Comment: Also your voice really doesn't change once you are an adult.

Comment: Puberty. You're going to hate a certain Brady Bunch episode... (Assuming everyone binges everything these days.)

Answer (score 6):

If a kid's voice will change through time, [deepening as they reach puberty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_change), most probably, their parents' voice won't and a quick search about [presbyphonia](https://www.google.com/search?q=Presbyphonia) may help you.

If you watch this movie with kids, in case they notice and ask, I think you can easily explain the voice's change with the body (throat / nose / mouth) modification as you grow up. Easier for a kid to understand the growth and the changes in volume and shape of the vocal tract and rib cage rather than hormones :)

It's quite logical that movie makers choose to keep the same voice as kids will, most of the time, hear only one tone of their parents' voice, the one they have as adults.